# Customizing a title section with titles package

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

Looking at the titlesec documentation I found a example suitable for me, so I made a little modifications and get something like this

[image]

with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\huge\normalfont\bfseries\filright}{\huge\cuadro{\thesection}}{0.5cm}{}

\newcommand*\cuadro[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introducción}
\end{document}
```

Now I am using tiki because maybe in a future a will add to the rectangle, So what I want is to add a line that starts in the right inferior corner of the box and covers all the section name, I've tried with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\huge\normalfont\bfseries\filright}{\huge\cuadro{\thesection}\rule[-4pt]{0.5cm}{1pt}}{0.5cm}{}

\newcommand*\cuadro[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\section{\underline{Introducción}}
\end{document}
```

And get something like this

[image]

That does the work but I am not very satisfied changing the rule options so there is less complicated way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Must your frame have a fised width or will it adapt to its contents?

Comment: You mean the section name? Yeah I would like to adapt to its name, about the number it is ok like that

Comment: And if  the number is, say `12.1`?

Comment: Well I haven't thought that also the number frame would be nice :)

Comment: The main problem is when the title has letters with descenders like “g” or ”p”. What would you do in this case? The underlining would cut the descenders or not meet the frame around the number.

Comment: @Very23 asumiré que hablas español. Quizás debas redefinir el diseño (y, por lo tanto, el comando `\cuadro`) poniendo el número de la sección y el nombre de la sección dentro de un cuadro más grande (y no solamente el número de la sección) y dibujar las líneas para este cuadro grande ...